# how to load multiple lazy css load file

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I want to use lazy load css techinque recommend by google page speed. 
First, I try to merge multi css file into one file but I got problem bootstrap is override the font size. I dont know why. i hav checked file arranged. bootstrap is loading first. however it still override.

So I want to load more than one css file with Javascript. here is code by google:

```
<script>
  var cb = function() {
    var l = document.createElement('link'); l.rel = 'stylesheet';
    l.href = 'css/test.css';
    var h = document.getElementsByTagName('head')[0]; h.parentNode.insertBefore(l, h);
  };
  var raf = requestAnimationFrame || mozRequestAnimationFrame ||
      webkitRequestAnimationFrame || msRequestAnimationFrame;
  if (raf) raf(cb);
  else window.addEventListener('load', cb);
</script>
```

How can I load more than one file with this code ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
var cb = function(href) {
        var l = document.createElement('link'); l.rel = 'stylesheet';
        l.href = href;
        var h = document.getElementsByTagName('head')[0]; h.appendChild(l); 
      };
```

Call `cb()` as many times as you need with different stylesheets

```
cb('css/style1.css');
cb('css/style2.css');
```

Comment: Thks :) it working. however it add before head tag. is it ok ? no need to add insert head tag right ? Thanks

Comment: Replace `h.parentNode.insertBefore(l, h)` with `h.appendChild(l);`

Comment: How do you setup the if (raf) raf(cb); else window.addEventListener('load', cb); part for multiple cb calls?